# How much wobble could be expected from tethering a moon to Ceres?

Tags: stability, space-tether

In the question "[Why put a big rock into orbit around Ceres?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/191182/69394)", another user posted an answer that suggested such a satellite, if actually tethered to Ceres, would generate so much wobble it would give the residents of the system whiplash. I disagreed, but don't have the math/physics background to actually calculate how much wobble would be present. So, I thought I'd bring the discussion over here, and have someone more knowledgeable answer.

Would tethering a 1km asteroid to Ceres create enough wobble from gyroscopic procession to actually be uncomfortable to someone on the surface? Assume that the asteroid is roughly the same density as Ceres, and that it's far enough away that centripetal force would be greater than Ceres' gravity (to keep the tether taut).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The surface gravity of such a moon would be measured in microgravities, the gravitational influence at the distance of Ceres would be far less, and any possible wobbling effect that a person on Ceres would be exposed to would be a small fraction of that. So, no.

Also, Ceres takes 9 hours to rotate, and any wobble would have a greater period. So again, no.

The referenced answer actually seems to be talking about the shift in the center of gravity of the system, not precession. All points on Ceres and the moon would be following circular orbits around the net center of gravity. There's nothing for the inhabitants to feel, the claimed wobble doesn't even exist.

Comment: You mention Ceres takes 9 hours to rotate. To be tethered to tbe planet, the orbit of the moon would have to synchronize with the orbit of Ceres, and remain above a specific spot as Ceres rotates. otherwise the tether just wraps around Ceres. Do you have the calculations and the data to determine the orbital distance from Ceres, and the orbital speed, to allow a tether to Ceres? And secondly, the OP does not consider this, but what would be the effect of regularly sending large masses of ore up the tehter, accumulating it, and then suddeny releasing it on its way to Earth?

Comment: I would presume the center of gravity would shift along the tether as material was moved from th esurface, up the tether, and then suddenly into space.

Comment: No further calculations are necessary, the effects only decrease with distance. As for removing material, I don't think you have any idea of the scales involved. The moon would mass roughly a billion metric tons, and Ceres about a billion times more than that. Removing the equivalent of the entire mass of the moon would make a change in Ceres' mass of one part per billion. This is negligible.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond The radius of an orbit synchronous with Ceres' sidereal rotation period (9.074170 h) is ~1191.8 km, which is (curiously) almost exactly 2.5× Ceres' equatorial radius (476.2 km). I used the period & GM from [JPL](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sbdb.cgi#top), and equ. radius from [NASA](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/dwarf-planets/ceres/by-the-numbers/), and this calculation in Google: `(6.26284E10*(1800*9.07417/pi)^2)^(1/3)`

Comment: @PM 2Ring Thank you, that is interesting. Almost twice as far as other figure I have seen. That makes the speed of the moon even greater, and the force it exerts on Ceres through the tehter even more.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond No worries. Perhaps those other figures were for the satellite's altitude above the surface of Ceres, rather than its radial distance from the centre of Ceres. I didn't include the tension of the tether in my calculation, only the (equal & opposite) gravitational forces that the satellite and Ceres exert on each other. An ideal weightless tether would have zero tension. A real tether has weight which must be supported, the satellite's in orbit, so it supports itself. ;)

Comment: @PM 2Ring Given that large quantities of ore and perhaps water might be traversing up the tether, I suspect there would undoubtedly be tension in the tether, and it would be even further from the planet. Any 'lifting' force applied directly to the tether by the elevator car would 'pull' the moon as well. It is the tension that I posit would in part apply a force on Ceres, in part leading to a wobble, One distance that was posited was 640 km. or so above the surface so that would be around 1100 km. from the center, which fits your data.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond you're talking about a shift in center of gravity several orders of magnitude smaller than a part per billion. I don't know how you can still fail to understand this. Apart from your apparent misconceptions about rotating bodies, the magnitude of any possible effect is going to be far from perceptible, it certainly isn't going to cause discomfort or injury.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff I know that a small stone chip embedded in a 50 pound car tire can cause a vibration that is very noticeable and will wear out the tires very quickly. Or is that vibration in the steering wheel that I feel just a manifestation of my lack of understanding of unbalanced rotating objects?

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond A 5 g chunk of rock in a 27 kg car tire is a couple hundred thousand times larger proportionally than this 1 km moon (never mind the payloads crawling along a tether connecting it to Ceres) and rotates a couple hundred thousand times as quickly. You don't see these differences as maybe being relevant?

Answer (score -4):

Let's look at this further.

There is a very big difference between the axis of spin (rotation), and the center of gravity. They do not need to be the same, and indeed in this situation, they are not. When the axis of rotation of a mass is not through the center of gravity of that mass, the result is a vibration determined in part by the frequency of the spin, and the distance of the offset mass from the axis of rotation. The further away the offset mass, the greater the amplitude of the vibration. The vibration is potentially further altered through harmonics and sub-harmonics, depending on the materials and structure of the mass.

I do not profess to the accuracy of some of these numbers, but they have been posited elsewhare.

Ceres is rotating every 9 hours. Has been for eons. That is a lot of momentum. In fact, it is the momentum itself that is acting like a motor, spinning the asteroid around an axis of rotation. Normally, this axis of rotation is also through the center of gravity. But this axis of rotation is NOT going to change just because the center of gravity changes. Momentum just does not work that way. The momentum determines the axis of spin, not the center of gravity. Eventually, with a change in the center of gravity, the axis of rotation will synchronize to it, but this takes energy, time, and force to happen.

So now we have a one km. diameter mass circling around this axis of rotation, being anchored through a tether, at a disatance of perhaps 600 km, (almost two thirds the distance again from the axis of spin than the surface). Recall that the artificial moon is orbiting at the same period of rotation as Ceres, in order for the moon to be over the same spot on the asteroid. So this mass is also orbiting the asteroid every nine hours. That amounts to some momentum. But this mass is also tethered to the asteroid, not through gravity, but through a mechanical connection. Where this mass goes, it mechanically pulls the asteroid with it. It does not have the luxury of escaping or moving to some higher orbit. That is, the orbit of the mass (moon) around Ceres is determind by the length of the tether and the axis of spin, not gravity or the center of gravity of Ceres. Note, the axis of rotation of Ceres does not change, even though the center of gravity changes along the direction of the tether.

The result is a center of gravity rotating around an axis of rotation, offset from the axis of rotation.

This is like a spinning motor with an offset mass on the shaft. Like an out-of-balance car wheel, it is going to create a periodic vibration. (Even a one gram mass on a car wheel rim can set up quite a noticeable vibration in the car if it is at a resonant frequency). But this motor is not attached to any rigid structure. It is wandering around in space. It is like a vibrating motor on a table, scuttling all over the place. Okay, not quite, this asteroid has a fair amount of momentum, inertia, in its orbiting velocity around the sun, held there by the Sun's gravity. Just like the vibrating motor can not fly too high off the table because of gravity, Ceres will vibrate, but only within a defined space around the sun. What happens to Ceres as a result of this vibration, of course, depends a lot on resonant frequencies.

So we have Ceres vibrating with a period of 9 hours, and wobbling a bit in its path around the sun. It will continue to do so, until the axis of rotation synchronizes with the center of gravity of the combined object. Given that the ratio of the diameter of the moon to the diameter of Ceres is about 1 in 1000, and the distance the moon is away from Ceres is 2/3 the diameter of Ceres itslef, we have a comparatively large mass offset by a considerable distance.

Now we have a mass of rock and water being sent up the tether, perhaps several tons an hour. That is the purpose of the operation - to mine resources from Ceres and send them to space. This has the effect of moving the center of gravity of Ceres further along the tether, without altering the axis of rotation. This mass accumulates on the moon, perhaps up to the diameter of the moon itself. Of course, this mass also rotates the same as the moon, one rotation every 9 hours. But it needs to gain momentum to do this. Not through reaction mass, but from the tether itself. Just like you can increase the speed of a bucket spinning around your head through the rope connecting it, this mass climbing the tether increases its speed, gaining the energy to do so through the tether and the rotation of Ceres, and the energy applied to the 'lift' up the tether.

Since it would not be economical to send just small buckets of material to Earth, the material sent up the tether would be accumulated into a large bundle, maybe equal to the diameter of the moon, but let's say these bundles were kept to just 10% of the mass of the moon. The small packets sent up the tether are all gathered together over time, and then they are discharged in one big mass.  Recall, this large bundle is moving at the same rate as the moon, synchronous to a spot over Ceres. A 10% reduction in mass results in a 10% increase in velocity of the moon, but this moon is still tethered to Ceres. It doesn't get to just speed up, or change direction, it is dragging an entire asteroid behind it. Even if the mass is somehow released from the moon over time, say one hour to separate, it is still a 10% change in momentum and inertia in a short time. Note that it is the momentum given to this bundle through its orbital velocity that will 'drive' it in a straight line tangentially away from Ceres, once released, and if aimed properly and released at the right moment, on its way to Earth. Only minimal reaction mass is necessary.There is minimal gravity pulling it back to Ceres.

The tension in the cable is going to be changed by this 10% mass reduction factor. It will cause a vibration in the cable (whiplash), the degree depending on resonant frequencies, which will be transmitted into Ceres at the point of connection of the cable.

So now there are two more periods added to the calculations - that of the timing of delivery of material to the moon, and the other due to the launch schedule of the bundle back to earth. Both having considerable influence on the total mass offset from the axis of rotation, and on the resulting vibration. Also, Ceres itself experiences a net loss of mass, primarily from one side, leading to a change in the center of gravity (without altering the axis of rotation), and indeed in the overall loss of momentum of the asteroid itself. This is not a mining operation that just moves mass from one place to another, re-arranging the landscape and keeping the momentum within the object, it is a mining operation that removes mass and its momentum completely from the asteroid. A great deal of mass.

Would people be uncomfortable? I have known people who get sea-sick on the top floors of 50 story buildings vibrating in high winds. Here we have a 600 km. high room attached through a tether to the 'ground', vibrating with a period of 9 hours and a harmonic of the frequency of the material coming up the elevator and another harmonic at the launch frequency of the bundle. In an enviroment devoid of the buffering effects of an atmosphere and the 'grounding' effects of gravity. They would certainly have to adjust. Hopefully, someone is monitoring the sub-harmonics of all of these frequencies.

I am not that fond of doing math, but I am going to give two links to the math that defines the vibration of offset loads on shafts of motors. I woud presume this math could be applied to determine how badly the vibration of Ceres would be, and how it would be modified by huge volumes of mass being added and then ejected from the moon. However, it highlights that the vibration of an offset load around an axis of rotation is dependent on the magniture of the mass, the distance it is offset from the axis of rotation, and the frequency.

From [here](https://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/content/ab-004-understanding-erm-vibration-motor-characteristics/) an idea of the motion (sorry, I do not know how to copy math formulas)

and [here](https://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/content/ab-027-eccentric-mass-parameters-for-vibration-motors/)

Comment: If an object is free to spin, then its axis of rotation must [go through its center of mass](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81029/do-objects-rotate-around-the-torque-vector-or-its-center). Altering the center of mass **does** move the axis of rotation. Eccentric-mass motors, such as the ones you linked, vibrate because the bearings in the motor constrain the axis of rotation to something other than what its natural rotation axis would be. Unless you mount Ceres on a giant motor, its axis of rotation **will** go through its center of mass.

Comment: "The result is a center of gravity rotating around an axis of rotation, offset from the axis of rotation." Impossible for the scenario described.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield  I am sorry, but that is just not how things work. There is this small thing called inertia and conservation of momentum. The axis of rotation does not instantly change to the centerof gravity, there is just too much force that has to be redirected. Read what I posted. The axis of rotation of Ceres goes through the centre of gravity BEFORE the centre of gravity is shifted. However, once the center of gravity is shifted, the axis of rotation no longer goes through the center of gravity. Basic physics.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond So, imagine that Ceres is a perfectly uniform sphere. Now, cut it into two pieces along a plane, but not through the axis of rotation, then take away the larger piece. This leaves the former axis of rotation sitting in empty space completely outside the piece that's left. Are you saying that the remaining piece would continue rotating around empty space?

Comment: No, the smaller piece would continue in a line tangent to the original orbit. There would be no more rotation around any axis of rotation. That is straight physics, pure and simple. There was never any 'rotation' in that chunk to begin with, no rotational momentum. The axis of rotation is all about the rotational momentum, not the center of mass.